# How to add a static text at end of a wordpress permalink

Tags: customization, permalinks, text

I am using simple/standard page hierarchy to get a permalink like:
https://domain.com/county/city

I just want to put state at the end like this:
https://domain.com/county/city-nj

I am unable to put "-nj" at end.

I tried to Custom Structure like:
https://domain.com//%postname%-nj

But it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a decent WordPress Way of doing this but a very effective Alternate. Please BACKUP your database before applying this solution.

I went to PHPMYADMIN and applied this query:

UPDATE `wp_posts`
SET post_name = CONCAT(post_name,'-nj')
where post_type = 'page' and post_parent <> 0

and all      https://domain.com/county/city
urls became  https://domain.com/county/city-nj

Please note that all "CITY" pages are child page of "COUNTY" pages in my case.